# Criando migrations usando module.exports

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Olá, estou tentando criar uma migration usando o knex, porem o knex não aceita o `export default` então como alternativa eu estou usando o modo de importação o ECS5 (ex: const knex = require('knex) e module.exports...). Porem ao tentar criar a migration usando o comando `npx knex migrate:latest` ele apenas retorna no console a mensagem `Already up to date` mas ao tentar visualizar a tabela usando a extensao do vs code `SQLite` ele não mostra a tabela que teoricamente era para ter criado

Bom, gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado, ja tentei de varios modos, tentei configurar para o knex aceitar o ECS6 mas não tive sucesso, se puderem me ajudar ficarei grato Obrigado !

Arquivo da minha migration

```
const knex = require("knex");

module.exports = async function up(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("help", function (table) {
    table.increments("id").primary();
    table.string("name").notNullable();
    table.string("email").notNullable();
    table.string("phone").notNullable();
    table.string("city").notNullable();
    table.string("uf").notNullable();
    table.string("neighborhood").notNullable();
    table.string("description").notNullable();
  });
};

module.exports = async function down(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("help");
};
```

Arquivo knexfile.js (sim está na raiz)

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  client: "sqlite3",
  connection: {
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "database", "database.sqlite"),
  },

  migrations: {
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "database", "migrations"),
},
    useNullAsDefault: true,
};
```

Arquivo de conexão com o banco

```
const knex = require("knex");
import path from "path";

exports.connection = knex({
  client: "sqlite3",
  connection: {
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "database.sqlite"),
  },
});
```

[image: extensão SQLITE do vscode]

Answer (score 0):

o `export default` deve ser usado quando voce exportar apenas um unico valor, funcao, objeto. [veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Usando_a_exporta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_padr%C3%A3o). 
o que talvez voce deveria fazer, ou tentar, utilizar o `export.` para os metodos `up` e `down`, e colocar o `await` logo apos o `return`. desta forma:

```
exports.up = async function(knex, Promise) {
 return await knex.schema.createTable('tasks', function(table) {
  // ....
 })
}

exports.down = async function(knex, Promise) {
 return await knex.schema.dropTable('tasks');
}
```

Tentou desta forma?

Comment: Olá, ja tinha tentado dessa forma, mas tentei mais uma vez apenas para ter certeza e ele volta naquilo que eu tinha falado, ele retorna apenas "Already up to date" mas nao cria a tabela no banco, quando eu tento visualiza-la com a extensa do SQLITE ele está vazio.

Comment: Bom, entao nesse caso, sugiro que apague essas tabelas de migrations do knex (`knex_migrations` e `knex_migrations_lock`), pois elas possuem todos os logs de migrations executadas. Ao executar sua migrations novamente (sem voce ter dado `rollback` nelas), se tiver algum registro nessas tabelas sobre a migration que voce quer rodar, o knex vai assumir que ja foi executada a migration e entao na precisaria executar novamente. Talvez por isso suas tabelas nao aparecem. Tente fazer o teste.